Transmission holograms
I would like to realize a transmission hologram for a college project. One of the requirements is to measure something with your own project. So I was thinking about measuring the diffraction index of some medias  (water or oil) by putting the object in a plastic box initially empty. If I develop the image on the plate of the object when box is empty and then that of the object in box filled with water, will I see any differences on the 2 images. If yes how could I use them to find the diffraction index?

Do you expect that the liquid medium will have an effect on what you see when you view the holographic image that is different from the effect that it will have when you view the original scene? If so, why?
